# Get highest count and corresponding value in Django query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a patient model with "disease" as one of the fields.
I want to count the top 5 diseases in all patient objects and return the counts for each of them. How could I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Patient.objects.values('disease').order_by().annotate(Count('disease'))
```

If You have the following data in your Patient table,

```
+---------+
| disease |
+---------+
| A       |
| B       |
| A       |
| C       |
| A       |
| A       |
| C       |
+---------+
```

The output will be :-

```
<QuerySet [{'disease': 'A', 'disease__count': 4}, {'disease': 'B','disease__count': 1}, {'disease': 'C', 'disease__count': 2}]>
```

---

There are many ways to find the max value from this output.

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models import Max

Patient.objects.values('disease').order_by().annotate(disease_count=Count('disease')).aggregate(maxval=Max('disease_count'))
```

Output will be :- `{'maxval': 4}`

### **OR**

```
from django.db.models import Count

query_result = Patient.objects.values('disease').order_by().annotate(disease_count=Count('disease'))
maxval = max(query_result, key=lambda x:x['disease_count'])
```

Output will be :- `{'disease': 'A', 'disease_count': 4}`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

I think the best approach would be to separate patient and disease in two different models like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    ...

class Disease(models.Model):
    patients = models.ManyToManyField(Patient) # One disease can have n patients
    disease_name = models.CharField(# Customize this as you want)
```

then in your method you can do this (it can be a model method or an external method):

```
def your_method_name():
    Disease.objects.all().annotate(num_patients=Count('patients'))\
                         .order_by('num_patients')[:5]
```